# Storing every value of a changing variable

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of code that takes an input that varies according to discrete time steps. For each time step, I get a new value for the input.
How can I store each value as a list?

Here's an example:

```
"""when t = 0, d = a
   when t = 1, d = b
   when t = 2, d = c"""

n = []
n.append(d)      #d is the changing variable
for i in range(t):
    n.append(d)
```

What I expect to get is:
`for t = 0, n = [a]; for t = 1, n = [a,b]; and for t = 2, n = [a,b,c]`

What I actually get is:
 `for t = 0, n = [a], for t = 1, n = [b,b];` and `for t = 2, n = [c,c,c]`

Comment: there no need for a loop here how do you get the input

Comment: It is being produced by another script.

Comment: So you are getting the input from a another script be more precise and you to add character to list as dis increased could you provide how you got the input from the other script

Comment: You will be getting t and d from the other script and you want to append the d value to a list

Comment: Yes! I want to store each value of d

Comment: Could you provide how you get t and d from the other script

Comment: without fully telling what you want you can not get the output.For which you have to provide everything in the question and add some more code

Comment: @VigneshKalai Thank you for your efforts. I will provide more code on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

See comment below, but based on the additional info you've provided, replace this:

```
n.append(d)
```

with this:

```
n.append(d[:])
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question is not about how to obtain those particular values for d, but about how to store them, as they are pre-defined (I have edited my question to make it more clear)

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code you're using? Is the block of code you posted part of a function/class? If you run the code I posted with the same parameters you posted, it returns the correct output list that you're expecting.

Comment: The piece is not part of a function or a class. It is written inside Grasshopper (plugin for Rhinoceros). I can't post the rest of the code because it is fragmented.
What I can actually add is that for every time step (t) the value of d is a (different) list of ints

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. In your initial post, d is just an int -- not a list of ints. Do you want to append the contents of that list "d" to your list "n"? Is "t" the length of the input list (let's call it "x") and d is the value at x[i]?

Comment: I want to append the whole list, so n ends up being a list of lists.

Comment: Ah, I think you just need to replace the "d" in your code with "d[:]". I put a comment on my edit that explains in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Which type is the variable 'd'? If it is, for instance a list, the code you are showing pushes onto tbe list 'n' a reference to the variable 'd' rather than a copy of it. Thus, for each iteration of the loop you add a new reference of 'd' (like a pointer in C) to 'n', and when 'd' is updated all the entries in 'n' have, of course, the same value
To fix it you can modify the code so as to append a copy of 'd', either:

- n.append(d[:])
- n.append(list(d))
- n.append(tuple(d))

Comment: Thank you.
d is a list. However, I think the problem is not related to the data type of the variable, but to the fact that as the value of d changes, previous values are not stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this

```
n = []
for i in range(t + 1):
    n.append(chr(i+ord('a'))
```

And if you do not want to store the characters in the list rather some specific values which are related with `d`, then you have to change `d` in the for loop

```
n = []
d = 1
for i in range(t + 1):
    n.append(d)
    d += 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not explained my self properly.
I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you again, but the question is not about how to obtain those particular values for d, but about how to store them, as they are pre-defined (being calculated by another piece of script)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without seeing the code. But if `d` is not an int, this could happen. If `d` is a list for instance, it is passed by reference

```
n = []
d = [1]
n.append(d)

d[0] = 2
n.append(d)
print(n)
>>>> [[2], [2]]
```

So if each new `d` is just modified, your probleme arise. You can solve it by copying d :

```
from copy import copy
n = []
d = [1]
n.append(copy(d))

d[0] = 2
n.append(copy(d))
print(n)
>>>> [[1], [2]]
```

Comment: Thank you.
As you say, the fact that d changes for every time step is creating my problem. So even if I copy d, it will copy the new value each time, and previous values of d are not stored.

Comment: @cmlcrz If you copy it before changing it, it will not be overwritten. See my example : you have all the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wrap the variable inside an object you can watch what is being set to the variable by overriding `__setattr__` method. A simple example.

```
class DummyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.history_of_x=[]
        self.x = x
        self._locked = True
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        if name == "x":
            self.history_of_x.append(value)

d = DummyClass(4)
d.x=0
d.x=2
d.x=3
d.x=45
print d.history_of_x
```

Output :-

```
[4, 0, 2, 3, 45]
```

Comment: Thank you @k4vin, but it didn't work for me. The value of the input variable that I am using as parameter for the class changes before it goes into the class, therefore the result keeps being the same: a list populated with the same element t number of times (t being time steps).